# Rad Window Telerik Control not displaying correctly on first display

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radwindow

I am working on an ASP.Net Project. I am using Rad window PopUp On a page.This opens on click on button.

But i am facing one problem. When the page loads for the first time,this window is not opening properly, i.e. some content missing for the first time on this window. But second time it
show all contents properly.

Please help.

Comment: Will you post some code so we can try to diagnose the problem? If not, perhaps a few more details will help.